# DevExtreme dxList change itemTemplate on mouse over

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, devexpress, devextreme

I have DevExtreme dxList:

```
<div data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: ds, itemTemplate: tpl }">
</div>

var vm = {
    ds: [{
        "key": "group1",
        "items": [{ name: "item1" }, { name: "item2" }]
    }],

    tpl: function() {
        var r = '<div data-options="dxTemplate:{ name:\'tpl\' }">';
            r += '<div data-bind="dxCheckBox: { text: name }"></div>';
            r += '</div>';
            return r;
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

How can I change itemTemplate run-time only for a specific item? (e.g. on mouse over)

Comment: Could you clarify how exactly you want to change item template? If you want to show some element on mouseover, you don't have to change item template.

Comment: You are right. I just need to show some element on mouseover, eg a textbox instead of static text. Because I need to allow the user to edit the text of groups and items

Comment: I need to allow the user to change the text of groups and items. 
How to change the static text to a dxTextbox run-time for the clicked item?
I also need to show save and cancel buttons on the edited item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change list item template you could use the following sample http://jsfiddle.net/oakvprw9/8/

This is the exemplary item template:

```
<div data-bind="dxList: { dataSource: dataSource, onItemClick: onItemClick }">
<div data-options="dxTemplate: { name: 'item' }">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: text, visible: !editEnabled()"></span>
        <div data-bind="visible: editEnabled">
            <div data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: text }"></div>
            <div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save', onClick: $root.saveChanges }"></div>
            <div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Cancel', onClick: $root.cancelChanges }"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the dxList is editEnabled = true mode by default, because I need the delete and reorder functionality. So this way how could I implement the reorder function by myself? I am very new in DevExtreme...

Comment: To enable reordering of list items you can use `editConfig: { reorderEnabled: true }, editEnabled: true` options. Also, you could use `onItemReordered` handler to assign a function to perform a custom action when a list item is moved to another position(see [documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxList/Configuration/?version=14_2#onItemReordered)). I've updated my previous sample [http://jsfiddle.net/oakvprw9/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/oakvprw9/15/)

Comment: This is cool. One last improvement: on save/cancel click the list item should go  back to the original layout (hide save/cancel buttons), but it doesn't work for me:  saveChanges: function(arg){
        var itemData = arg.model;
    arg.model.editEnabled(false); //Why doesn't work?
}

Comment: You could try to use `<!-- ko if -->` virtual element instead `visible` binding. I've updated my sample [http://jsfiddle.net/oakvprw9/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/oakvprw9/16/)